# Mystery switch with a 12V voltage difference to ground

Tags: electrical, switch

I have one extra switch that doesn't seem to do anything. All other switches are accounted for, and so are all the lighting fixtures and outlets. It has 3 wires going into it - black, white and bare (ground). The wiring seems normal. I checked them with a multimeter, and there is no voltage difference between any of the 3. So basically I assumed the entire wire was disconnected somewhere.

However, I then decided to check them against a different ground wire from a nearby switch on a different circuit. To my surprise, all 3 showed a voltage difference of 12V! Even ground to ground it is 12V. You can even get voltage this with the faceplate on, just by touching the two outside faceplate screws.

I have no idea which circuit breaker even controls this switch, but flipping one I suspect might be related seems to reduce the voltage by half to 6V.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no hot wires attached to the switch then the voltage measurements may be meaningless and showing some phantom potential with no current.

> ground to ground it is 12V.

Ground wires (EGC) are required to be bonded throughout the system.  There should never be potential between two ground wires.  This suggests the switches are not installed correctly.

Theoretically, if you had 2 switches in a plastic box, where one of them is an abandoned switch loop and none of the wires are spliced, then you could get voltage indications similar to this due to the ground wire being ungrounded (open).  This condition is not necessarily safe and should be corrected.

If this is a single switch in a single box then it is likely ungrounded and should be removed.